# Pysphere error when running playbook

Tags: yaml, ansible, pysphere

```
---
- hosts: my-host
  tasks:
    - vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: vcenter.mydomain.local
        username: myuser
        password: mypass
        guest: newvm001
        vmware_guest_facts: yes
```

When I run this playbook, I get this error

> PLAY [my-host]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [setup]
>   ******************************************************************* ok: [19.3.112.97 ]
>
> TASK [vsphere_guest]
>   *********************************************************** fatal: [19.3.112.97 ]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg":
>   "pysphere module required"}
>
> NO MORE HOSTS LEFT
>   *************************************************************  [WARNING]: Could not create retry file 'createvms.retry'.
>   [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
>
> PLAY RECAP
>
> ---
>
> 19.3.112.97                : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Why do I get this error? I have uninstalled and installed pysphere. I have used previous and current versions of it but I still get this error.

Comment: You installed psyphere on the control host? How?

Comment: I used pip install.  'sudo pip install  pysphere'

Comment: My initial thought is that you have more than one python installed on your system and Ansible is using the "wrong" one.

Comment: That makes sense. Let me look further into it and see if that is the case. Thanks

Comment: @mwp   What is a datacenter again? And how do I get the correct datacenter to use? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. A datacenter is where servers and other devices are racked, cooled, and connected to network and power.

Comment: Please check this question out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278444/error-trying-to-create-a-new-vm-in-ansible?noredirect=1#comment65891560_39278444

Comment: Thank you!! I understood what a datacenter was from that video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually want to run cloud/VM management modules from your control machine (localhost).
This would look like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: vcenter.mydomain.local
        username: myuser
        password: mypass
        guest: newvm001
        vmware_guest_facts: yes
```

In this case ansible use PySphere installed on your control host to connect to `vcenter.mydomain.local` and provision VMs.

In your example PySphere should be installed on `19.3.112.97` and `vcenter.mydomain.local` should be accessible from that host.

Comment: Hello. What is a datacenter again? And how do I get the correct datacenter to use? Thanks